# Collaboration with Dropbox Business

Tags: dropbox, collaboration

We've just started to use Dropbox Business. Our files are organized in subfolders, for example:

```
Clients > Company-A > Design
Clients > Company-A > Development
Clients > Company-B > Design
...
```

We're working together with a design company. At the moment they share their top-level folder called "Company-A-Design" with some of our team members, so that some of our team members have a top-level folder "Company-A-Design" in their account. But we want all team members to have access and the files should be placed in "Clients > Company-A > Design". Right now, we just copy the contents from "Company-A-Design" to "Clients > Company-A > Design" manually.

Is it possible to share a folder in a way, that it can get integrated in our folder structure as shown above? Or can we share the "Clients > Company-A > Design" subfolder with that design company? As far as I can see, there's just the option "Shareable Link" (I hope this is the correct wording as we're using the german UI), which is not the same as a shared folder, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

In dropbox you are not allowed to share a folder which already has a shared folder in it. To reduce multiple sharing , there is a limitation to not allow this kind of multiple sharing between folders for the users in the company.